# Definition of Linear Independence of solutions of first order linear homogeneous differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

In the book *Differential Equations An Introduction to Modern Methods and Applications* by James R. Brannan, William E. Boyce, Chapter 6.2. The theorem 6.2.5 says gives the definition of linear independency of solutions of a system of first order linear homogeneous differential equations. It states as follows,

[image]

My question is that does there exists such a set of solutions that their Wronskian equals 0 at finite number of points. If it does, what is the linear independency of such kind of solution set? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the Wronskian is nonzero at $ t_{0}$ means that the square matrix $P(t)$ on the right is nonsingular, hence this equation has only the solution $ c_{1} = c_{2} =...c_{n} = 0,$ so $ x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n} $ are independent.
Notice that in this case it was enough to find the Wronskain nonzero at any one point in the domain - it might not be nonzero everywhere (that is, it might be zero at some points in the domain). Also, we get “by pure logic”, the contrapositive of this statement, which says that if $ x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n} $ are dependent, then their Wronskian is zero at all points in the domain.
Next notice that for arbitrary $x_{1}, x_{2},$  the Wronskian does not provide a test for dependence. As a counterexample, let $ x_{1}(t) = t|t|$ and $x_{2}(t) = t^2.$
 Then you can check that the Wronskian of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ is always zero, but these functions are independent.

Comment: I think here $x_1,...,x_n$ are all vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The key point is that the Wronskian of solutions are either always $0$ or never $0$ in the domain, which can be seen from Abel's theorem.